# How to improve the performance in Lucene when query is long?

Tags: lucene

I have been using Lucene to build a POI searching & geocoding system. After test, I found that when query is long(above 10 terms). And the speed of searching is too slow near to 1s. I think the bottleneck is that I used OR to generate my BooleanQuery. It would get plenty of candidates documents. And it would also consume too many time to score and rank.

I changed to use AND to generate my BooleanQuery. But it decrease the accuracy of hits. So I want to find a solution to reduce candidate documents and do not decrease the accuracy in this situation.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you could express your query as a filter, you could cache it (by wrapping your filter in `CachingFilterWrapper`) and reuse the same instance across searches.

We have a case where query length is hundreds of terms and performance went from ~4 seconds to hundreds of milliseconds (~10 times faster).

Comment: Thanks mindas~ caching and reusing these instances would speed up search. But after study api, I found a better way by using BooleanQuery#setMinimumNumberShouldMatch method to require the number of terms that the candidate docs should match. Finally, searching service have been improved tripled faster.